# Failed to login in Testlink - Not saving session / cookies

Tags: php, session, azure, cookies, testlink

I'm having problems deploying a Testlink in a client server. It seems that the origin of the problem is that **it's not saving / retrieving information in session correctly**, and this causes errors during installation and attempting to logging.

During installation a variable is stored in session (*installationType*) indicating whether it is a new installation or an updgrade. This variable takes the value 'new', but when moving from one screen to another that value is lost, assume that I'm performing an upgrade and it is impossible to continue. As a workaround I made changes to the code to set this variable to 'new' on each screen and that way I finished the installation proccess correctly. But when I try to login I find another problem: after entering user data and access, **the screen refreshes and redisplay the login screen** without any error message (in fact the log shows that the login was successful). This behavior is the same as disabling cookies in the browser.

The same version of Testlink (1.9.14) has been installed without problems on a local server with an identical configuration:

> - Ubuntu: 14.04.1 (64 bit)
> - Apache: 2.4.7
> - PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16
> - MySQL: 5.5.49

The difference is that our Ubuntu is mounted on a virtual machine within Debian, and Ubuntu client is deployed in Azure.

I have compared the php.ini configuration on one machine and another and I haven't found significant differences. Comparing the info showed by phpinfo() neither I found nothing relevant (could attach both here if needed), but I see that in the "PHP Variables" section of the local server I have this cookie:

> COOKIE [ "TESTLINKUSERAUTHCOOKIE"]

This cookie does not appear in the client server (I guess is not being created after login).

My guess is that there's something in the Azure administration panel (which I don't have access) to be configured, in the same way that opening a port need to be done both on the iptables and in Azure.

Any suggest would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Mystery resolved. The problem wasn't related with Azure, but with the own server configuration.

After comparing all the configuration files of Apache and PHP against a fresh installation, I have found this:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**000-default.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
    # Commented out, because fcm4 use external JavaScript
    # Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header unset X-Powered-By
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "master-only"
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
        Header unset X-Frame-Options
        Header unset Content-Security-Policy
        Header unset X-XSS-Protection
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The lines that were causing this behavior were:

- Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
- Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"

After commented out, everything it’s ok.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Php session problems are usually related with temporal folders used by Apache/Php to work with.

I guess Testlink implements a quite classic cookie based session system. Follow this article to be sure you are configuring session handling properly.

https://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP

You may be also interested in this link. It's a step by step guide about Testlink installation on Azure machine:

http://thusharapriyantha.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/install-testlink-1913-stormbringer-in.html?m=1

Get Lucky... Kind regards

Comment: Thank you Manuel, but no luck. Second link is one of the guide I followed step by step, and I've checked all the parameters in your first link and everything is ok.

Comment: After talking with Giles and do some tests with Lynx connecting directly from the server, it seems that the problem is related with the own server configuration, and not related with Azure.

I will keep trying, but at the end (and before killing myself) if I don't get it I'm going to deploy the Bitnami Testlink virtual machine (although is not my best option and could lead to other problems).

Thanks again!

Comment: hey! don't give up!  Let's try another solution. keep in touch